# External table columns having integer value but starting with 0 as string via Glue crawler

Tags: web-crawler, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have created a crawler to run over a S3 path having csv files. It creates a Redshift External table with bigint column for fields having integer value and string column for fields having alphanumeric value.

Is there a way i can force the crawler to define fields as string when it encounters value like "002" or "0123" i.e. integer values but starting with 0.

Note: I do not know which columns will have such values beforehand.